# Iteration over a pandas Series taking forever, but I can't think of a way to solve this without it. Is there a faster way?

Tags: optimization, pandas, iteration, vectorization

I have a pandas Series of successive numbers, something like

```py
import pandas as pd
D = pd.Series([2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    index=pd.date_range(start='2015-01-02 12:00:00', periods=16, freq='s'))
D

2015-01-02 12:00:00    2
2015-01-02 12:00:01    3
2015-01-02 12:00:02    4
2015-01-02 12:00:03    4
2015-01-02 12:00:04    5
2015-01-02 12:00:05    4
2015-01-02 12:00:06    3
2015-01-02 12:00:07    2
2015-01-02 12:00:08    3
2015-01-02 12:00:09    4
2015-01-02 12:00:10    5
2015-01-02 12:00:11    4
2015-01-02 12:00:12    3
2015-01-02 12:00:13    2
2015-01-02 12:00:14    1
2015-01-02 12:00:15    0
Freq: S, dtype: int64
```

However, my particular dataset has maybe a million rows. I am interested in answering the following question for each row:

> For each row `i` and a fixed positive number `s`, let `S` be the next index after `i` such that `D[S]<=D[i]-s`. What is the maximum value of `D[j]-D[i]` for `j` between `i` and `S`?

To provide some intuition for the problem, the data is a price series for a stock index, and I am interested in knowing, at each time, what is the highest price change that the series achieves before setting off a stop loss order at price `s`. For instance, with `s`=2, we are looking for the largest peak between now and when the price reaches its current level minus 2.

I've written a function that finds this for a given row. First, I take the first difference of `D`, and then run

```py
def pmax(Ddiff, i, s):
    values = Ddiff[i+1:].iteritems()
    pmaxvalue = 0
    pcurrentvalue=0
    while pcurrentvalue>s:
        try:
            pcurrentvalue += values.next()[1]
        except StopIteration:
            return pmaxvalue
        pmaxvalue = max(pmaxvalue, pcurrentvalue)
    return pmaxvalue
```

and running

```py
peaks = []
for i in range(len(D)):
    peaks.append(pmax(Ddiff, i, -2))
```

gives the correct output on the toy dataset. But it takes an infeasibly long time on my actual dataset.

I've racked my mind trying to come up with a vectorized way to do this, but I can't.

Can anyone think of a way to do this faster?

Answer (score 1):

For your toy example, your solution is remarkably fast, however it scales quite bad:

- 10 rows --> 1.3ms
- 100 rows --> 31.5ms
- 1000 rows --> 2160ms
- 5000 rows --> 52500ms

I'd suggest a more numpy based approach like

```py
# create big dataframe
n = 1000
D = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,6,n),
    index=pd.date_range(start='2015-01-02 12:00:00', periods=n, freq='s'))
# compute differences
Ddiff = D.diff()
# compute cumulative sum of differences
Dsum = Ddiff.cumsum()
# set initial value from nan to 0
Dsum[0] = 0

def pmax2(Dsum, D, i, s):
    # find index S
    S = np.argmax(D.iloc[i+1:]<=D.iloc[i]-s)
    # get max amplitude
    l = np.max(Dsum.iloc[i:i+S+1]-Dsum.iloc[i])
    return l

# compute for all individual entries
peaks = []
# use xrange instead of range
for i in xrange(len(D)-1):
    peaks.append(pmax2(Dsum, D, i, 2))
peaks.append(0)
```

This scales like

- 10 rows --> 1.79ms
- 100 rows --> 19.7ms
- 1000 rows --> 200ms
- 5000 rows --> 1040ms

If you need more speed you could think about parallelizing the for loop.